# Finding value in list in pandas column by index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I have a dataframe with many columns that are lists of values, which are floats. I would like to find the element or elements in these lists based on an index, which is an integer or integers in a separate column. Eg.

```
Results                                             Index_1 Index_2

0   [2.347, 140.8, 1010.8, 723.7, 7, 0, 2.898, 9.1...   0   [0, 4, 6]
1   [93794, 112.7, 5.014, 0, 1778.1, 3473.82, 0, 3...   1   [1, 5]
2   [2.927, 12.647, 9047, 0, 1204.5, 13.4, 6.3, 4....   2   [2, 0]
3   [0, 1.801, 7.104, 2121.2, 20.375, 6.348, 11.35...   2   [2, 9, 3]
```

What I would like is to create two columns with the values of the results based on Index and Index_2. Eg.

```
Results                                             Index_1 Index_2    Outcome  Outcome_2
0   [2.347, 140.8, 1010.8, 723.7, 7, 0, 2.898, 9.1...   0   [0, 4, 6]   2.347   [2.347, 7, 2.898]
1   [93794, 112.7, 5.014, 0, 1778.1, 3473.82, 0, 3...   1   [1, 5]     112.700  [112.7, 3473.82]
2   [2.927, 12.647, 9047, 0, 1204.5, 13.4, 6.3, 4....   2   [2, 0]     9047     [9047, 2.927]
3   [0, 1.801, 7.104, 2121.2, 20.375, 6.348, 11.35...   2   [2, 9, 3]   7.104   [7.104, 12531.5, 20.375]
```

The Results vary in number and so does one of the indexes.

For some reason the `index` function does not work and I get thrown errors including:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

This is when I run `df['Outcome'] = df['Results'].index['Index_1']`. I've played around with the code but cannot seem to get this to work.

I have checked the dtypes of the columns and they return `list` for Results and `numpy.int64` for Index_1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply lambda function that can do that:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Results','Index_1','Index_2'],
  data=[[[2.347, 140.8, 1010.8, 723.7, 7, 0, 2.898, 9.1], 0,   [0, 4, 6]],
  [[93794, 112.7, 5.014, 0, 1778.1, 3473.82, 0, 3],1,   [1, 5]],
  [[2.927, 12.647, 9047, 0, 1204.5, 13.4, 6.3, 4],2,   [2, 0]],
  [[0, 1.801, 7.104, 2121.2, 20.375, 6.348, 11.35],2,   [2, 6, 3]]])

for x in [1,2]:
    df[f'Outcome_{x}'] = df.apply(lambda row: (np.array(row['Results'])[row[f'Index_{x}']]).tolist(), axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.to_string())
                                           Results  Index_1    Index_2  Outcome_1               Outcome_2
0  [2.347, 140.8, 1010.8, 723.7, 7, 0, 2.898, 9.1]        0  [0, 4, 6]      2.347     [2.347, 7.0, 2.898]
1  [93794, 112.7, 5.014, 0, 1778.1, 3473.82, 0, 3]        1     [1, 5]    112.700        [112.7, 3473.82]
2   [2.927, 12.647, 9047, 0, 1204.5, 13.4, 6.3, 4]        2     [2, 0]   9047.000         [9047.0, 2.927]
3  [0, 1.801, 7.104, 2121.2, 20.375, 6.348, 11.35]        2  [2, 6, 3]      7.104  [7.104, 11.35, 2121.2]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It did the trick.

Because of the doubling-up of terminology for pandas and python, namely "lists" and "indexes", it is very hard to find solutions searching. Pandas also feels like a new language on its own.